# Reload Spring Properties

Tags: java, xml, spring, properties, javabeans

This is for a college project:
I am using the Spring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to obtain values from a property 
file. I am updating the properties file from a GUI via the following code:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
FileOutputStream out = null;
out = new FileOutputStream("pro.properties");
prop.setProperty("durationpro", "wk");
prop.store(out, null);
out.flush();
out.close();
```

I have tried using two methods to get the updated file to work:
http://www.wuenschenswert.net/wunschdenken/archives/127
and I tried to refresh the context application directly after the file update

```
ApplicationContext f = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("Bean1.xml");
((ConfigurableApplicationContext)f).refresh();
```

My code

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Bean1.xml");
BeanFactory factory = (BeanFactory) context;
TestGUI t = (TestGUI) factory.getBean("testbean");
```

While the application is running (I don't have to close application) I have to manually open and close the properties file and then the change is recognised.  This happens for both methods

The xml file I am using for the spring refresh method is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">


<bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer"   
class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">  
  <property name="locations">  
    <list>  
      <value>classpath:pro.properties</value>  
    </list>  
  </property>  
</bean>   

<bean id="com" class="Domestic" /> 

<bean id="wk" class="Week" />

<bean id="mth" class="Month" />

<bean id="testbean" class="TestGUI"> 

  <property name="customerType" ref="com" /> 
  <property name="duration" ref="${durationpro}"/> 

</bean>

</beans>
```

I copied the xml file exactly for the other Wunschdenken method

Thanks for any help

Comment: I am trying to get the xml file to recognise when the properties file has been changed and reload the new property name duration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind - I had the properties file in the source folder, moved it out and implemented
http://commons.apache.org/configuration/ and all works fine